# Add image next to site title in Wordpress website

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to add a image to the left of the site-title: [mysimpledevotion.com](http://mysimpledevotion.com)
How can I do that?
Would it be easier to make an image of both the text and pic, rather than trying to just add a small pic (icon) next to the text? I'm not talking about the favicon but rather the site-title MY SIMPLE DEVOTION on the front page.

Comment: It really depends on the site and HTML structure. Can you post a link?

Comment: www.mysimpledevotion.com

Comment: `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">` put this in your `<head>`. replace favicon.png with your image icon URL

Comment: Do you want a favicon or do you want an image next to the actual title on the page (My Simple Devotion)?

Comment: Yes, I know what a favicon is, that's not what I am talking about. I mean actually on the page. Next to the H1 header that is the site-title MY SIMPLE DEVOTION on the website.

Comment: http://www.mysimpledevotion.com/web-mysimple.jpg

This image shows what I am trying to do.

Comment: Tom, yes. That is what I am wanting to do. An image next to the actual title on the page.

Comment: Really? 2 votes down? Thanks guys.

Comment: Yes. It is a wordpress site.

Comment: How do I add code to this discussion to show you what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

I found two options to achieve this.

**1. Using CSS `before` to inject the image**

The major problem with this approach is that you cannot use relative paths; i.e, the image url must be absolute, otherwise it will not work consistently on all pages of the website.

To do so either add the following CSS to the "Additional CSS" part of your theme (when customizing it), or add it in the `style.css` of your custom child-theme (and make sure to add the `style.css` using the `functions.php` correctly).

```css
.site-title a:before{
  content:"";
  background-image:url('http://path/to/my/image.jpg');
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 1em 1em; 
  width: 1em; 
  height: 1em;
}
```

This will make the image correspond to the text size as well, and you can add additional CSS properties such as `border-radius: 50%`.

**2. Using theme's filters to inject image**

This approach heavily relies on the used theme to define appropriate filters where you could inject the image HTML. Here is an example of injecting an image to the Astra theme using a custom child-theme.

`functions.php`:

```php
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}

if( ! ( function_exists( 'wp_get_attachment_by_post_name' ) ) ) {
    function wp_get_attachment_by_post_name( $post_name ) {
        $args           = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'name'           => trim( $post_name ),
        );

        $get_attachment = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( ! $get_attachment || ! isset( $get_attachment->posts, $get_attachment->posts[0] ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        return $get_attachment->posts[0]->guid;
    }
}

add_filter( 'astra_site_title', 'add_image_to_site_title' );
function add_image_to_site_title( $original_title ) {   
    $image = wp_get_attachment_by_post_name( 'my-image-post-name' );
    $html = '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="" class="title-image">';
    return $html . $original_title;
}
?>
```

`style.css`:

```css
/*
 Theme Name:   My Astra
 Template:     astra
*/

.title-image {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em; 
    height: 1em;
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

That is called favicon and can be added, if you are using theme which has that option included then can be checked by Theme Options within your wordpress admin (check on the left side). If it's isn't there then check Appearance >> Customize.

Even you cannot find there then check theme documentation. Try avoiding adding any additional code, it might conflict with existing.

Even it's not in theme documentation then do following steps to add it

1. Go to Appearance >> Editor
2. Click on header.php
3. Add the following code between `<head></head>`

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="your-image-link" />`

Comment: Good information but this is not an answer, it's a comment. The question is too broad for an answer

Comment: Yes, I know what a favicon is, that's not what I am talking about. I mean actually on the page. Next to the H1 header that is the site-title MY SIMPLE DEVOTION on the website.

Comment: Do you mean to put image to look like it's a logo?

Comment: http://www.mysimpledevotion.com/web-mysimple.jpg

This image shows what I am trying to do.